# How to modify dropdown list?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

Currently my bootstrap dropdown list looks like this:

[image]

'Logout' button works correctly but somehow 'Log out' link does not work. Could you take a look and fix my 'Log out' link?

```
<div class="logout-dropdown-list float-right">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <p align="right">Logged as <span sec:authentication="name"></span></p>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <form action="#" class="float-right" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout">
        </form>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">Log out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            **HTML**

            <div class="logout-dropdown-list float-right">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <p align="right">Logged as <span sec:authentication="name"></span></p>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <div class="custom-dropdown-item">
                      <form action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" value="Logout" class="dropdown-item">
                    </form>
                    </div>

                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">Log out</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            **CSS**
            .custom-dropdown-item{display:block;}
            .custom-dropdown-item input{border:none !important; border-radius:none !important; cursor:pointer; outline:none !important; box-shadow:none !important;}

            DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/0fpgLk6h/
```